# nodemailer multiple email sending using SMTP causes connection close errors

Tags: smtp, nodemailer, transport

I am having problems when I do a looped call to Mailer send email function.I am testing sending of over 50 emails and the most number of successfully sent were 30 so far. The rest is stopped by the following errors. I redacted the complete email address for the robot for privacy reasons.

> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] INFO  [0rULO04aig] User "xxx.robot@xxxxxx.com"
>   authenticated
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] INFO  [#1] Sending message
>   <3299d22a-e0c8-00b8-4f7d-4d0455f85b31@xxxxx.com> using #1 to
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [0rULO04aig] C: MAIL FROM:
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [PFhdqz3yHs] S:
>   250 2.1.0 OK v72-v6sm36109733pfj.22 - gsmtp
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [PFhdqz3yHs] C: RCPT
>   TO:
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [0rULO04aig] S: 250 2.1.0 OK
>   v186-v6sm24113856pgd.25 - gsmtp
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [0rULO04aig] C: RCPT
>   TO:
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [PFhdqz3yHs] S: 250 2.1.5 OK
>   v72-v6sm36109733pfj.22 - gsmtp
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [PFhdqz3yHs] C: DATA
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [BlXN9zcX8Ak] S: 421 4.7.0 Temporary
>   System Problem.  Try again later (10). x65-v6sm28504837pfk.140 - gsmtp
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [BlXN9zcX8Ak] Closing connection to the
>   server using "end"
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] INFO  [#1] Connection #1 was closed
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] ERROR [#1] Pool Error for #1: Data command
>   failed: 421 4.7.0 Temporary System Problem.  Try again later (10).
>   x65-v6sm28504837pfk.140 - gsmtp
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] ERROR Send Error: Data command failed: 421 4.7.0
>   Temporary System Problem.  Try again later (10).
>   x65-v6sm28504837pfk.140 - gsmtp
>
> [2018-09-03 05:18:32] DEBUG [gflzBwS1fc] S: 421 4.7.0 Temporary System
>   Problem.  Try again later (10). b203-v6sm1382852pfb.174 - gsmtp

I am unable to post the complete code since the checker here keeps telling me that it is not properly formatted. The code follows ESLint rules.

Let me post a pseudocode:

```
forEach(users, key) =>
    getSQL
       create Users if no result found
         sendEmail(user)
```

So the settings:

```
function Mailer(options) {
  this.options = options;
  that = this;
  this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    pool: true,
    maxConnections: 50,
    maxMessages: Infinity,
    debug: true,
    logger: true,
    connectionTimeout: 3000,
    host: config.mail.host,
    port: config.mail.port,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
          user: config.mail.username,
          pass: config.mail.password,
        },
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir. Thank you for editing my question.

Do I need to provide more details?

Comment: The logs reveal a server-side problem but we have no access to your SMTP provider's server logs. Ask them.

Comment: Hi Triplee. The SMTP provider is google. I am using smtp.gmail.com.

Comment: Quick googling suggests they have blacklisted your IP. Again, nothing we can do.

Comment: Really? Can you send me a link? I've been googling this for several days now.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gmail+421+4.7.0

Comment: This one seems particularly pertinent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284228/gmail-smtp-error-421-4-7-0